# Android close services or only pause when need memory?

Tags: android, service, background

I'm trying to do a service to continue to work indefinitely in the background and if it ends, be restart by itself.
works well for a while, but 30 or 40 minutes then stops sending signals, but the service still continues in list. and never enters OnDestroy ().

I do not know if android really stops or only pause. I think not pause because I wait a long time and never again show signs of life.
Here is a part of my code. test reasons, simply do an infinite loop that displays a message every minute in the notification bar.

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      Log.i("Timer", "Service starting" );


      new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                Runit();
            }
        }).start();

      return START_STICKY;
  }

 private void Runit(){

      Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Timer started.");
      try {

          while (true){
              Thread.sleep(60000);
              iTimer += 1;                   
              new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                  public void run() {
                      SendNotification("Timer "+String.valueOf(iTimer));
                  }
              }).start();

          }

      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        SendNotification(e1.getMessage());

      }

    SendNotification("Service Stop");

}
```

I did another test using startForeground (), and thus lasted two days working until I stopped it. but I do not want to display in the notification bar.

which is the reason it stops working? android pause it or stop it?

Comment: By definition `START_STICKY` will restart the service when killed.

Comment: I know, but not why it does not restart

Answer (score 0):

When android needs to free some memory it **kills** processes that occupy that memory. Pausing would make no much sense as paused process still could lock the resources.

Your test case is ineffective - nobody sane would do busy loop on mobile. If you need to do something each minute set recurring alarm and do your job as fast as you can.

Comment: well, the truth is I'm starting to develop mobile and I'm still not very familiar with some methods. If android kills processes, START_STICKY should not restart?